# Simple jQuery slideshow / Pause onClick (of Image)

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
$("#slideshow > div:gt(0)").hide();

setInterval(function() { 
  $('#slideshow > div:first')
    .fadeOut(1000)
    .next()
    .fadeIn(1000)
    .end()
    .appendTo('#slideshow');
},  3000);
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/camny77/WgRtp/embedded/result/

I just would like to add a feature to ***STOP*** `onClick`

..and then RESUME, `onClick`.

Comment: Have you tried the jQuery `stop` function? http://api.jquery.com/stop/ or the `clearInterval` function?

Comment: or the [jQuery Cycle](http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle/) plugin?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the [clearInterval](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.clearInterval) function to clear the interval, and thus make the animation stop.

Maintain a variable to check the status of the animation, whether it is active or not, and just toggle it when a click event happens.

The following code will make the animation stop when you click, and resume again when you click it.

```
var _animate  = '';
var active = 1;
function animate() {
    _animate = setInterval(function() { 
      $('#slideshow > div:first')
        .fadeOut(1000)
        .next()
        .fadeIn(1000)
        .end()
        .appendTo('#slideshow');
    },  3000);
}


$("#slideshow").bind(
    'click' , function() {
        if (active === 1) {
            clearInterval(_animate);
            active = 0;
        } else {
            animate();
            active = 1;

        }
    }
);
$("#slideshow > div:gt(0)").hide();
animate();
```

​I've edited your fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/WgRtp/3/

Comment: Thanks - this is awesome; but I need onClick - not onHover - this is for iPad.

Comment: Oh. Sorry my bad, revised it :)

Comment: Hey Pranav - This seemed to only work when a SPECIFIC frame was clicked; it didn't seem to be consistent. I'm thinking it's your line 'if (active === 1) {' -- I tried toggling it to 'all' '1,2,3' -- but then the anything working just DIED -- can you help?

Comment: @whoa : It seems to be working (http://jsfiddle.net/WgRtp/9/) , could you clarify what exactly breaks ?

Comment: It works within the fiddle; but for some reason using the EXACT same code on a live server via FTP -- will not render the same.

Comment: It would be great if you could pass a link. 
Are you calling the function after the DOM is ready? Append the code in between `$(document).ready(function(){})`; 

If you are already doing that, and  copying and pasting from the fiddle, sometimes an invisible character gets added in the end, make sure that is not happening.